# How to get client side validation on a date string model property

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my model I have an object that contains a date property. (String is used because that is what the previous programmer wrote):

```
[Display(Name = "Payment Date")]
[Date(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid date")]
public string PaymentDate { get; set; }
```

Here is the custom date attribute used by `PaymentDate`:

```
public sealed class DateAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable 
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var dateString = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dateString))
        {
            return false;
        }
        DateTime result;
        var success = DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out result);
        return success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule 
        { 
            ValidationType = "paymentdate", 
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } 
        };
    }
}
```

This works great on the server side, but not on the client side.
Here in the view I tried to create a custom function to do the validation, but it does not seem to work properly. There is a syntax error caused by the dot before `test`

```
    // custom jquery validation method    
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('validDate', function (value, element, params) {
        return Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)); 
    }, '');

    // unobtrusive adapter
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('paymentdate', {}, function (options) {
        options.rules['validDate'] = true;
        options.messages['validDate'] = options.message;
    });
```

How can I get client-side validation working with my already-working server side validiation?

Note: I'm using a custom attribute because some custom validation will be added later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is thrown because the regex is not valid, you need a `/` at the beginning

```
/Invalid|NaN/.test(...)
```

However, couple of things I would point out.

1. It's recommended you use [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) when parsing date strings
2. It's better to use the [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function when checking for `NaN`

Here's a revised version of your validator

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validDate', function (value, element, params) {
    return !isNaN(Date.parse(value)); 
}, '');
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed as suggested, but still nothing. The non custom attributes work propery (an error is shown instantly after moving away from the field), but the custom attribute is not working.

Comment: @navig8tr what do you mean by "*fixed as suggested*"? Have you just fixed the regex or are you using the recommended approach provided?

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested (I'm not using the regex solution because I will need custom validation).

Comment: The validator name has to match the adapter name, you will need to change `validDate` to `paymentdate`.

Comment: Okay all names match, but it still not working...maybe I should try to get working on a new page. There may be something on the page messing it up...

Comment: Start with the simple things - put a break point in the functions & make sure the code is getting hit (that rules out the wiring). Check for errors in the console - if all else fails then I'd perhaps look at creating a sandboxed page to diagnose the problem.

Comment: After placing a breakpoint in the method (the one shown in this post), it is hit on initial page load. Should it be hit when the page is posted?

Comment: @navig8tr if you are placing the breakpoint *inside* the `addMethod` then it should be getting hit whenever you attempt to post the form or navigate out of the field, not on page load.

Comment: Okay the function is working. However, it only checks for null. How do I validate that it is a valid date?

Comment: @navig8tr the code in my example doesn't just check for `null` dates, it also checks for invalid dates. `Date.parse` will return `NaN` if the date is not valid, I suggest you read the docs I have linked to for `Date.parse` as there are potential [pitfalls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Fall-back_to_implementation-specific_date_formats) you may need to watch out for.

Comment: Okay, it's working as it should...just not the way I want it to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68114/discussion-between-james-and-navig8tr).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.validator.addMehod('validDate', function (value, element, params) {
        return Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)); 
    }, '');
```

with

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('validDate', function (value, element, params) {
        return Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value)); 
    }, '');
```

Looks like you're missing a t in the function.

Comment: I was indeed missing a t, but it didn't fix the issue.